# Remove NA values efficiently

Tags: r, eigen, rcpp

I need to remove `NA` values efficiently from vectors inside a function which is implemented with RcppEigen. I can of course do it using a `for` loop, but I wonder if there is a more efficient way.

Here is an example:

```
library(RcppEigen)
library(inline)

incl <- '
using  Eigen::Map;
using  Eigen::VectorXd;
typedef  Map<VectorXd>  MapVecd;
'

body <- '
const MapVecd         x(as<MapVecd>(xx)), y(as<MapVecd>(yy));
VectorXd              x1(x), y1(y);
int                   k(0);
for (int i = 0; i < x.rows(); ++i) {
 if (x.coeff(i)==x.coeff(i) && y.coeff(i)==y.coeff(i)) {
  x1(k) = x.coeff(i);
  y1(k) = y.coeff(i);
  k++;
 };
};
x1.conservativeResize(k);
y1.conservativeResize(k);
return Rcpp::List::create(Rcpp::Named("x") = x1,
                          Rcpp::Named("y") = y1);
'

na.omit.cpp <- cxxfunction(signature(xx = "Vector", yy= "Vector"), 
                   body, "RcppEigen", incl)

na.omit.cpp(c(1.5, NaN, 7, NA), c(7.0, 1, NA, 3))
#$x
#[1] 1.5
#
#$y
#[1] 7
```

In my use case I need to do this about one million times in a loop (inside the Rcpp function) and the vectors could be quite long (let's assume 1000 elements).

PS: I've also investigated the route to find all `NA`/`NaN` values using `x.array()==x.array()`, but was unable to find a way to use the result for subsetting with Eigen.

Comment: I suppose there's no way to remove the `NA` earlier on in the process?

Comment: Unfortunately not. In my real use case I pass three matrices to the function and do regression between corresponding column vectors. And for that I need to remove NA cases. So I need something like `na.omit` in `lm`. I don't want to do the loop over column indices in R.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Perhaps I am not understanding the question correctly, but within Rcpp, I don't see how you could possibly do this more efficiently than a `for` loop.  `for` loops are generally inefficient in R only because iterating through a loop in R requires a lot of heavy interpreted machinery.  But this is not the case once you are down at the C++ level.  Even natively vectorized R functions ultimately are implemented with `for` loops in C.  So the only way I can think to make this more efficient is to try to do it in parallel.

For example, here's a simple `na.omit.cpp` function that omits `NA` values from a single vector:

```
rcppfun<-"
Rcpp::NumericVector naomit(Rcpp::NumericVector x){
std::vector<double> r(x.size());
int k=0;
  for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); ++i) {
    if (x[i]==x[i]) {
    r[k] = x[i];
    k++;
   }
  }
 r.resize(k);
 return Rcpp::wrap(r);    
}"

na.omit.cpp<-cppFunction(rcppfun)
```

This runs even more quickly than R's built in `na.omit`:

```
> set.seed(123)
> x<-1:10000
> x[sample(10000,1000)]<-NA
> y1<-na.omit(x)
> y2<-na.omit.cpp(x)
> all(y1==y2)
[1] TRUE
> require(microbenchmark)
> microbenchmark(na.omit(x),na.omit.cpp(x))
Unit: microseconds
           expr     min       lq   median      uq      max neval
     na.omit(x) 290.157 363.9935 376.4400 401.750 6547.447   100
 na.omit.cpp(x) 107.524 168.1955 173.6035 210.524  222.564   100
```

Comment: +1 -- At the end of the day you will have to look at each element (i,j). You can disguise the looping behind some magic, but why not keep it simple and do as suggested here?

Comment: Yes, I've used something like this now and it is fast enough. But keep in mind that `resize` doesn't conserve the data in Eigen.

Comment: Did you try to test via is_na() ?  Makes the intent more explicit then then comparison.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel No, I didn't try that, I basically copied the code from the OP.  I couldn't tell you off the top of my head how to deal with R values of NA and NaN in C code, so I just assumed the OP had it right.

Comment: Out of curiosity I tried to make a version that would use two passes : one for count the number of NA, one for grabbing them directly in a `NumericVector`. The idea was to save the extra copy from the `std::vector<double>` to the `NumericVector`. This was slower than your version.

Answer (score -1):

I do not know  if I understand the problem correctly or not but you can use the following arguments:

```
       a = c(1.5, NaN, 7, NA)
       a[-which(is.na(a))]
       [1] 1.5 7.0
```

It might be useful to use `rinside' if you want to use it in C++.

Comment: I don't want to do this with plain R but with Rcpp. With R I would just use `na.omit`. Using `RInside` will most likely be rather slow in comparison to pure Rcpp/RcppEigen.

Comment: There is a fair amount of confusion in this answer. RInside is for making separate applications with R inside. This is in a way the opposite of Rcpp which aims to put C++ code inside R.